# JQuery how to avoid next() method chaining

Tags: jquery, html

Full working JSFiddle of my problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5mhu02n/).

I'm have a form that has multiple child forms:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form>
  <ul style="list-style-type: none">
    <li class="panel panel-body panel-default">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label clas="control-label" for="1_sample">Sample</label>
        <input type="number" id="1_sample" name="1_sample" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
                <span class="sr-only">100% Complete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label clas="control-label" for="1_result">Result</label>
        <input type="number" id="1_result" name="1_result" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label clas="control-label" for="1_number">Number</label>
        <input type="number" id="1_number" name="1_number" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </li>
        <li class="panel panel-body panel-default">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label clas="control-label" for="2_sample">Sample</label>
        <input type="number" id="2_sample" name="2_sample" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
                <span class="sr-only">100% Complete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label clas="control-label" for="2_result">Result</label>
        <input type="number" id="2_result" name="2_result" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label clas="control-label" for="2_number">Number</label>
        <input type="number" id="2_number" name="2_number" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

The coded behavior is that when a `sample` input changes, the `result` and `number` inputs in the same `li` change together.

My JQuery currently looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('form');
    form.on('change', 'input[id$="sample"]', function (e) {
            var sample_field = e.target;
            var result_field = $(sample_field).closest('.form-group').next().next().find("input[id$='result']");
            var number_field = $(sample_field).closest('.form-group').next().next().next().find("input[id$='number']");

            var sample = $(sample_field).val();

            $(result_field).val(sample);
            $(number_field).val(sample);
    });
});
```

What I'm wondering is whether there is a way to avoid the `next()` chaining to get the the correct form groups? In the real code, the `next()` chains are very long, and also not very robust to the additional or removal of elements.

`find()` by itself doesn't seem to explore the `.form-group` elements for the inputs - is there a better way to code this functionality?

**Update:**

JSFiddle with code updated to reflect accepted answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2bh2x2zb/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the element using **$('form').find()** like following to avoid next() chaining

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('form');
  form.on('change', 'input[id$="sample"]', function (e) {
    var sample_field = e.target;
    var result_field = $('form').find("div.form-group > input[id$='result']");
    var number_field = $('form').find("div.form-group > input[id$='number']");
    var sample = $(sample_field).val();

    $(result_field).val(sample);
    $(number_field).val(sample);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form>
    <ul style="list-style-type: none">
      <li class="panel panel-body panel-default">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label clas="control-label" for="1_sample">Sample</label>
          <input type="number" id="1_sample" name="1_sample" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
            <span class="sr-only">100% Complete</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label clas="control-label" for="1_result">Result</label>
          <input type="number" id="1_result" name="1_result" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label clas="control-label" for="1_number">Number</label>
          <input type="number" id="1_number" name="1_number" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/v5mhu02n/3/

Comment: Thanks - In my particular case the snippet was `$(sample_field).closest('.form-group').parent().find("div.form-group > input[id$='result']");`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are keeping the structure of your form inputs identical, Meaning the naming structure of the ids follows a specific pattern:

```
1_sample, 1_result, 1_number 
2_sample, 2_result, 2_number 
3_sample, 3_result, 3_number  
...
```

Then there is a more elegant solution where you can target the id of the input field directly. Consider the following update to your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('form');
    form.on('change', 'input[id$="sample"]', function (e) {
            //Get number prepended to id
            var formGroupIdx = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[0]; 

            //Get specific inputs using a concatenation of the prepended 
            //index and the default description of the input
            var result_field = $('#'+formGroupIdx+'_'+'result');
            var number_field = $('#'+formGroupIdx+'_'+'number');

            var value = $(this).val();
            result_field.val(value);
            number_field.val(value);
    });
});
```

For a given input ending in "sample", it would first fetch that pretended number (1,2,3...). Then it will directly get the corresponding results and number inputs using that index value. Finally it sets the value equal to the current sample input.

Updated **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5mhu02n/2/)**